# GMP powm function in Rust is giving incorrect results

Tags: rust, modulo, gmp, exponential

I cloned this repository to learn more about how it uses gmp within Rust:

https://github.com/poanetwork/vdf

Just for an accuracy check, I wrote a snippet to check the powm function:

```
    let modulushex = hex::decode("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").unwrap();
    let modulus = ffi::import_obj(&modulushex);
    let basehex = hex::decode("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").unwrap();
    let base = ffi::import_obj(&basehex);
    let exphex = hex::decode("32f71783ecf103a837c132bfa93ae921").unwrap();
    let exp = ffi::import_obj(&exphex);
    let resultshex = hex::decode("00").unwrap();
    let mut results = ffi::import_obj(&resultshex);
    ffi::mpz_powm(&mut results, &base, &exp, &modulus);
    println!("results [{results:?}]");
```

This gave the answer:

```
6263682918507965914797445799289859108134103890488175732832898635052307612005730308824743390072513383012259400947965457535695477018975847005106015411057214608601835313194847404520388830993945571946551059770249346550450799679293019212260731875429995408104700787836471924904040903046217160901192277414306953243692570745939155084293970373747868634274159689150356885218721451773167280878150568254478484035380265847143829453206348515440010212597926192674567686562177604430455586964510741165008495200814486437791770994880260554814576029215340442206760818180177707323413999025814877848350881462395129912997094278796497268895
```

However, checking the results online at:

https://www.dcode.fr/modular-exponentiation

gave the results:

```
13290134286600559171336036011744051010975349698089310497613244954971894256159455376070068170969117865603940143950234700490139328324510110590331351375373057750302635253248860322705105526282078955986713129738320950314362163296004383736966075522132464507202444974868495696938214081994773272806795593381322361519649717482608890203601703744375411728441852817229531187473366661448194569129834537136314700647178693515797801638221759683217309314651463861673829648093408577585291858800808060958176326026588397720716615414584950132753461667369058887493888335444980276376067415273068893192825129868694805775390603459613462318603
```

I have also checked this calculation in Javascript using the BN library, and it matches up with the online calculator. Could this be an issue with how gmp is being incorporated into rust?

Comment: Is this the only example you have where they diverge?

Comment: Also, is it completely necessary to have everything encrypted? For example, have you tried simply passing unencrypted numbers to `powm`? For all we know, this could be an issue with the decoding functions and not `powm`.

Comment: Hi Joseph, yes, I have tried smaller constants and they work, which led me to try loading the hex constant using this:
```
    let mut modulushex = Mpz::new();
    modulushex.set_from_str_radix("c7970c...1cc7e5", 16);
```
and now the results match up.

I wonder if the modulus input is too large for hex::decode to handle?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including imports within the post.